# Sort ListView by IP

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a ListView which contains data of type

`class InfoItem
        {
            public string IP { get; set; }
            public string MAC { get; set; }
            public string HOST { get; set; }
        }`

Event handler PingCompletedCallback gets IPs in random way, so we can`t predict order of Ips. We need to Sort them. Im using this

```
if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {

                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    lstNetworks.Items.Add(new InfoItem() { IP = e.Reply.Address.ToString(), MAC = macAdress, HOST = hostName });
                    lstNetworks.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("IP", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
                }));
            }
```

and it is partially works, but the result looks like this

192.168.1.1
192.168.1.10
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.254
192.168.1.3
and so on...

How can we sort this ListView items in right way

192.168.1.1
   192.168.1.2
   192.168.1.3
   192.168.1.10
   192.168.1.254

## UPDATE. I tried to do like in that question:

```
List<InfoItem> list = new List<InfoItem>(); 
foreach (var item in lstNetworks.Items) { 
list.Add(item as InfoItem); 
} 
List<InfoItem> list2 = new List<InfoItem>(); 
list2 = list.Select(Version.Parse).OrderBy(arg => arg).Select(arg => arg.ToString()).ToList();
```

but it gives me and exception The type arguments for method Select cannot be inferred from the usage.

Comment: You need to create a custom sort for the IP address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort list of Ip Addresses using c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248039/how-to-sort-list-of-ip-addresses-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @Evan Trimboli Sort array of ips is not a problem, i need to sort it and not to loose dependency between IP MAC and HOSTname. So i need to sort all List

Comment: It's exactly the same problem. You need to sort the list of `InfoItem` by ip. Lists are sortable.

Comment: How can i do it: List<InfoItem> list = new List<InfoItem>();
                        foreach (var item in lstNetworks.Items)
                        {
                            list.Add(item as InfoItem);
                        }
                        List<InfoItem> list2 = new List<InfoItem>();
                        list2 = list.Select(Version.Parse).OrderBy(arg => arg).Select(arg => arg.ToString()).ToList(); gives me and exception The type arguments for method Select cannot be inferred from the usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer, you can use `Version.Parse` to do it:

```
public class Thing {
    public string ip;
}

var list = new List<Thing>() {
    new Thing() { ip = "192.168.1.1" },
    new Thing() { ip = "192.168.1.10" },
    new Thing() { ip = "192.168.1.2" },
    new Thing() { ip = "192.168.1.254" },
    new Thing() { ip = "192.168.1.3" }
};
var sorted = list.OrderBy(item => Version.Parse(item.ip));
foreach (var item in sorted) {
    Console.WriteLine(item.ip);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a customer IComparable class

```
public class MyIP : IComparable<MyIP>
{
    List<int>subAddress = null;
    public MyIP(string IPstr)
    {
       subAddress = IPstr.Split(new char[] {'.'}).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
    }
    public int CompareTo(MyIP other)
    {
       int results = 0
       if(this.subAddress[0] != other.subAddress[0])
       {
          results = this.subAddress[0].CompareTo(other.subAddress[0]);
       }
       else
       {
          if(this.subAddress[1] != other.subAddress[1])
          {
             results = this.subAddress[1].CompareTo(other.subAddress[1]);
          }
          else
          {
             if(this.subAddress[2] != other.subAddress[2])
             {
                results = this.subAddress[2].CompareTo(other.subAddress[2]);
             }
             else
             {
                results = this.subAddress[3].CompareTo(other.subAddress[3]);
             }
          }
       }
       return results;
    }

}​
```