# Using custom comparer for strings

Tags: c#, string, iequalitycomparer, stringcomparer

I have following list:

```
var ips = new List<string> {
    "192.168.5.1",
    "192.168.0.2",
    "192.168.0.3",
    "192.168.0.4",
    "192.168.1.1",
    "192.168.1.2",
    "192.168.1.3",
    "192.168.1.4"
}.OrderBy(p => p.Ip);
```

It looks like it works, Is it necessary to write a custom comparer like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631626/6311003):

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            int ip1 = IPAddress.Parse(x).ToInteger();
            int ip2 = IPAddress.Parse(y).ToInteger();
            return (((ip1 - ip2) >> 0x1F) | (int)((uint)(-(ip1 - ip2)) >> 0x1F));
        }
 }
```

Comment: OK. Now what is your question?

Comment: yes, its is necessary 118.168.5.1 1.198.6.7. compare with this data

Comment: `.OprderBy(p => p)` is the correct command and it doesn't require any custom comparer.

Comment: Use `IPAddress.Parse(x).ToInteger()` in the anonymous function.

Comment: @newbie could you explain why you are actually are comparing, what is the expected result ? *(Is it necessary to write a custom comparer)* ... depends what, how, why you want to compare ...

Comment: @Jim Actually I want my users to search between two ranges of IPs in my application. something like `between` in TSQL

Comment: @newbie edit your question with necessary details. It will improve the chance to get a decent answer. *(What do I want it to do, what I am doing, what it does, what I expect it should have done)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this example.

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.10
192.168.0.200
```

If you apply `OrderBy`, It will give you this result.

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.10
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.200
```

So you have to make your own custom comparer like the below example.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4785462/6527049